Integrability of a Sobolev function
Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, $n\geq 2$ be a bounded domain and $0<s<1$ and $\alpha,q>1$. Assume that $u:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ is a measurable function such that $u\in W^{s,q}_{\mathrm{loc}}(\Omega)$ such that for every $k>0$, we have $T_k(u)^{\frac{\alpha+1}{2}}\in W^{s,q}_{0}(\Omega)$.
Here $T_k(u)=min(k,u)$ and $W^{s,q}(\Omega)$ is the fractional Sobolev space defined by
$$
W^{s,q}(\Omega)=\left\{v:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}:v\in L^q(\Omega),\,\frac{v(x)-v(y)}{|x-y|^\frac{N+qs}{q}}\in L^q(\Omega\times\Omega)\right\}.
$$
The space $W^{s,q}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is defined analogously. The space $W_0^{s,q}(\Omega)$ is defined by
$$
W_{0}^{s,q}(\Omega)=\left\{v\in W^{s,q}(\mathbb{R}^n):v=0\text{ in }\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\Omega\right\}.
$$
My question is from the above assumptions on $u$ is it possible to conclude that the nonlocal integral
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\frac{(u(x)-u(y))(\phi(x)-\phi(y))}{|x-y|^{n+2s}}\,dx dy
$$
is finite for every $\phi\in C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$ (the space of smooth functions with compact support in $\Omega$).
I tried the approach from Proposition 2.3 of the paper https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1361-6544/acda0a/pdf (its available from research gate)
Where the above double integral is spilt into three integrals. The first integral if finite from our assumption as well, but the finiteness of the second and third integral is unclear, which mainly require that $u\in L^1(\Omega)$, which is unclear to me.
So the question reduces to if we can prove that $u\in L^1(\Omega)$, under the above given hypothesis on $u$, that is $u\in W^{s,q}_{\mathrm{loc}}(\Omega)$ such that for every $k>0$, we have $T_k(u)^{\frac{\alpha+1}{2}}\in W^{s,q}_{0}(\Omega)$. But again this is one direction to prove the above double integral finite. Without $L^1(\Omega)$, if the finiteness can be proved that is also ok.
Can someone please help me with this. thanks a lot.

Can you define $T_k$?

Thanks. I defined it now. Also you can assume u is positive in $\Omega$.
